# How to connect and read/write file to a local computer on iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, connection, local

i have a problem with local network connection. i'm writing an iphone application and i need to read/write files to a computer. Both devices connected on the same network.

if it's possible, i want to get connected computers ip list, select one of them and read/write files like pdf, doc, txt etc.. if it's not possible to do, i will write the computer ip which i want to connect. There is no problem, both of solution is OK.

But i dont know what do i do after get the computer's ip ?
i found [this](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/) chat client/server on local, but i got it very complicated.

Anyone have any idea about this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found exactly what i want. The solution is [here](https://github.com/38leinaD/tango)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have a server running on the computer, which can show files and allow for files to be read and created.

Easiest is to run a webdav service on the computer, Apache provides the mod_dav module for this purpose.

The iPhone app then becomes the client. I'd suggest using [neon](http://www.webdav.org/neon/) for this purpose. It's a C library that provides listing, reading and writing files on a remote webdav server.

Comment: i think having server is not necessary, because i can connect to the target computer from another computer. And i can read/write any files from there while the target computer doesnt have any server.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it.

1) Find the network address of the computer you want to connect to. For this you can make use of [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29). It's very easy to setup because Bonjour handles the resolving of address for you.

- You just have to publish a service (e.g. _myprotocol._tcp) via the ´NSNetService` class which is available on iOS and OS X (Windows too)- in your case you would publish the service on your computer.
- Then you search for the service with the `NSNetServiceBrowser` class.
- When you found a service you can then resolve it. This actually gives you the network name of the other device.

2) Connect to the other device via a tcp socket. The [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) library is very good at this. This project also includes some examples. One example already provides a bonjour server and client implementation.

Comment: oh dude, i lost arround services.. i'm confused, i have an iphone application and there is a computer on same local network as iphone, the computer sharing a folder, i just trying to write there a file. but i'm so confused now, as i understand bonjour working in here, i create a "NSNetService" and see it on bonjour client, but i dont know how to connect to the shared folder."_myprotocol._tcp" is tcp connection protocol as i understand, but what should be windows shared service protocol? can you help me about this?

Comment: The communication between your devices is handled with a tcp socket connection. One device writes data into the socket, the other one reads data from the socket. You are responsible for parsing the data and storing it in a folder. Before you can establish a connection, you have to know the address you want to connect to (e.g. 192.168.0.5 on port 52031). Bonjour helps you in this regards by abstracting IP addresses. With Bonjour you can work with service name. Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html)